# Postgres Interval with Dapper & npgsql not working

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I am using Dapper with Postgres npgsql and I am having trouble executing an SQL command using `INTERVAL`.
The command works fine outside my code.

I get the error

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at or near "$1"
>
> POSITION: 85'

Position 85 is exactly where the parameter @ageInDays is located.

My code is

```
int ageInDays = 90;
string mysql = "DELETE FROM Monitorvalues m1 WHERE lastupdate < current_date - INTERVAL @ageInDays DAY";

using (var connection = GetConnection)
{
    var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
    dynamicParameters.Add("ageInDays", ageInDays);
    return await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(mysql, dynamicParameters);
}
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Npgsql doesn't support parametrized `INTERVAL` clause. One possible solution here is to define a variable and then directly pass to it.

```
var ageInDays = 90;
var interval = $"INTERVAL '{ageInDays} days'";
var query = $"DELETE FROM Monitorvalues m1 WHERE lastupdate < current_date - {interval}";
return await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(query);
```

This should work without problems

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do: `var query = $"DELETE FROM Monitorvalues m1 WHERE lastupdate < current_date - INTERVAL '{ageInDays} days'"`?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Absolutely ! Wrote this way just for deeper explanation.

Comment: @AVTUNEY Thanks for the answer.  A bit disappointing that it is not supported, but then I will just work around it as you suggested.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - Npgsql definitely supports parameterized intervals; it's just that PostgreSQL does not support parameterizing literal expression `e.g. `LITERAL ...`). The proposed method above of using string concatenation instead of parameterization exposes the application to SQL injection and causes different SQLs for different `ageInDays` values, which hurts performance in a significant way. This should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

You need to parameterize the entire interval value, passing it as a TimeSpan:

```cs
conn.Query("DELETE FROM Monitorvalues WHERE lastupdate < current_date - @Interval", new { Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(2) });
```

As an alternative, if you really need to create an interval based on a parameterized number of days, you can use the `make_interval` PG function for this:

```cs
conn.Query("DELETE FROM Monitorvalues WHERE lastupdate < current_date - make_interval(days => @Days)", new { Days = 2 });
```

PostgreSQL doesn't allow parameterizing a literal expression (`INTERVAL ...`), that's why your code didn't work.