# Npgsql C# Update Parameterized Statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I'm attemtping to execute the parameterized update statement in C# below. My solution does not use Dapper so the following post ([Postgres Interval with Dapper & npgsql not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75731436/postgres-interval-with-dapper-npgsql-not-working)) does not apply.

```
            NpgsqlConnection  _command = _dataSource.CreateCommand(
                "UPDATE \"BulkProposal\" SET \"UploadDataJson\" = NULL WHERE \"CreatedDate\" <= NOW() - INTERVAL  @deleteInterval 'days' AND \"UploadDataJson\" is not NULL;");

            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("deleteInterval", _deleteIntervalInDays);
            _npgsqlConnection.Open();
            recordsDeleted = await _command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

When the statement above is executed I receive the following error:

```
Unexpected Exception: 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"

POSITION: 92 | Exception Details: Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"

POSITION: 92
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|233_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataSourceCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataSourceCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at BulkProposalDataPurge.BulkProposalDataPurge.FunctionHandler() in /home/abell/dev/proposal-service-lambdas/BulkProposalDataPurge.cs:line 53
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42601
    MessageText: syntax error at or near "$1"
    Position: 92
    File: scan.l
    Line: 1188
    Routine: scanner_yyerror
```

The problem seems to be related to the

```
@deleteInterval 'days'
```

I've also tried the variation of

```
'@deleteInterval days'
```

Not certain how to fix this.

Comment: Your parameter should start with `@`  as following `_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deleteInterval", _deleteIntervalInDays);`

Comment: Current Npgsql doesn't support parametrized INTERVAL clause.  I had the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75731436/postgres-interval-with-dapper-npgsql-not-working

Comment: @JGH Your answer was the best. I had to use the make_interval() function.

Answer (score -1):

The way you're using the parameter in the SQL query is the cause of the problem you're having. The parameter name does not need to be included in single quotes in the SQL statement itself when using parameterized queries with Npgsql. Instead, use the parameter name exactly as it is. Try the following code, where I changed your SQL statement.

```
NpgsqlConnection _npgsqlConnection = _dataSource.CreateCommand(
    "UPDATE \"BulkProposal\" SET \"UploadDataJson\" = NULL WHERE \"CreatedDate\" <= NOW() - INTERVAL @deleteInterval days AND \"UploadDataJson\" is not NULL;");

_npgsqlConnection.Parameters.AddWithValue("deleteInterval", _deleteIntervalInDays);
_npgsqlConnection.Open();
recordsDeleted = await _npgsqlConnection.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Before running this code, make sure _deleteIntervalInDays is set to the correct number; it should be the number of days you intend to use for the interval.
Hope it works :)